# GMP Transaction Stuck at Approving Stage

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, axelar

i have an issue with a transaction getting stuck at the step "Approving", when i click on it there's an error saying there's not enough confirmations yet, (at the time of writing there's 792 confirmations) tx on AVAX  : https://snowtrace.io/tx/0xea3129b6d780331aaf5f280e3d446d91061f04b67d345e4b8b2948a1c5a12e81
gmp tx : https://axelarscan.io/gmp/0xea3129b6d780331aaf5f280e3d446d91061f04b67d345e4b8b2948a1c5a12e81:12. If someone have any clues of why this happen this would be cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAVAX is not available on BNB. It is on Avalanche that's why it the tx succeeds at first but gets stuck on the destination chain